# How to update a directory across systems using ssh?

Tags: linux, windows, git, patch

**Background:**

With working from home being the new normal, I started using my personal Windows laptop
to complete my work, and then transfer the files over to my job's Linux pc.

Since my team uses a git repo I decided to copy said repo unto my laptop, and developed scripts that would transfer the files I work on over to my work computer using scp. However, now that we've been working for a long time, the repo on my work computer contains the many files other members of my team have worked on. I'd like to keep the copy on my laptop updated with all the files the rest of my team has done.

Copying over the entire repo again would take a long time and using git patch doesn't seem like a solution since the directory on my laptop is independent of the git project. And due to company policy I cannot use my laptop to create a remote repo of the project.

**QUESTION**

What can I do to keep the directory on my laptop, up to date with the directory on my job's computer, given that the only connectivity I can use between the two is through ssh?

Comment: What *does* the company policy allow?   At some point, you'll need a first-class shared repository that everyone on your team uses, and the longer you wait, the more difficult it's going to be to merge everyone's changes together.

Comment: Setting policy questions aside, are the 2 computers sitting one next to the other? You can set up one of them to have a web server so that you can publish one of the repos, I would assume? Then you could add that repo to the other computer as a remote and then you should be able to fetch which should be fast enough given that it's a local-network operation, right?

Comment: @Robert Harvey Only the use of ssh to connect to our work computers from our personal ones. There is already a repo where all the changes are merged. The copy on my laptop is to make my life easier and have my teammates files locally available without having to use the terminal. I need a way to patch the copy of the repo in my laptop with my local repo on my work computer.

Comment: @eftshift0 work computer is at the offices, personal computer is with me at home

Comment: If you want to keep directories _in sync_ **low-level** through ssh, you should see the kind of wonders that rsync can do for you (and make sure you understand how to use it before you go crazy... I take no responsibility so make sure you test it before going live).

Comment: You may consider using sshfs, after checking it's compliant with company policy.